# Converting groups of binary vectors into one column

Tags: r

I have multiple binary vectors indicating whether someone belongs to a certain group in R:

```
    Group1 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
    Group2 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
    Group3 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
    Group4 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
    Group5 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
    Group6 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
    Group7 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
    Group8 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
    Group9 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
    d <- data.frame(Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4, Group5, Group6, Group7, Group8, Group9)
```

I am trying to put all of this information into a column called "Group" so that those in `Group1` would have a value of `1`, those in `Group2` would have a value of `2`, etc...

Also, some individuals may belong to multiple groups. Because of this, I would like each individual to be placed into the highest group possible (with `Group1` being the highest). For example, someone who is in groups 2, 4, 5, and 9 would have a `Group` equal to `2`.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: are you looking for `max.col(d)`??

Comment: Definitely looking for a bit more than that.

Comment: then you should give an example data and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stack overflow, try to be a bit more respectful to the people answering your question

I think you have a row-wise problem where you need to first find out what are the column numbers that are equal to 1, and then you need the minimum column number, the following tidyverse code should solve this problem quite clearly

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

Group1 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
Group2 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
Group3 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
Group4 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
Group5 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
Group6 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
Group7 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
Group8 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
Group9 <- rbinom(100,1,.5)
d <- data.frame(Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4, Group5, Group6, Group7, Group8, Group9)

d %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(groups = min(which(c_across(everything()) == 1)))
#> # A tibble: 100 x 10
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 Group6 Group7 Group8 Group9 groups
#>     <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#>  1      1      1      1      0      0      0      0      1      1      1
#>  2      1      0      1      0      1      0      0      1      1      1
#>  3      0      0      1      0      1      1      1      0      0      3
#>  4      1      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      1      1
#>  5      1      1      0      1      1      0      1      1      1      1
#>  6      1      1      0      1      0      1      0      1      0      1
#>  7      1      1      1      0      1      1      1      0      1      1
#>  8      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2
#>  9      1      1      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      1
#> 10      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1
#> # ... with 90 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think `max.col` as suggested by @Onyambu should work along with `ties.method = 'first'` which will give you the first value in case of tie.

```
d$Group <- max.col(d, ties.method = 'first')
d

#   Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group
#1       0      1      0      1     2
#2       0      1      0      1     2
#3       1      1      1      1     1
#4       0      0      0      1     4
#5       1      1      0      1     1
#6       1      0      0      0     1
#7       0      1      1      1     2
#8       1      1      0      1     1
#9       0      0      1      1     3
#10      0      0      1      0     3
```

**data**

```
set.seed(568)
Group1 <- rbinom(10,1,.5)
Group2 <- rbinom(10,1,.5)
Group3 <- rbinom(10,1,.5)
Group4 <- rbinom(10,1,.5)
d <- data.frame(Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` with `apply` to find the where the first `1`

```
apply(d, 1, match, x=1)
#[1]  1  2  3 NA
```

or `TRUE` is.

```
apply(d, 1, match, x=TRUE)
#[1]  1  2  3 NA
```

Data:

```
(d <- data.frame(g1=c(1,0,0,0), g2=c(0,1,0,0), g3=c(0,1,1,0)))
#  g1 g2 g3
#1  1  0  0
#2  0  1  1
#3  0  0  1
#4  0  0  0
```